# Any idea on this USB interface type?

Tags: usb, cables, usb-device

The USB charging port is on a AOBO spy camera, ive no charging cable and this doesnt appear to me to be standard.

Instructions with the device indicate it is a USB interface port. The instructions do not indicate which type of USB cable is required, but did originally come with one.

It's definitely not type C or B or micro B or mini B.

It also appears to be 8 pin

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know it is a usb plug?

Comment: @PlasmaHH what else would you suggest it is...
The instruction manual points to this with a little arrow that says USB interface

Comment: at that many pins I would say its proprietary

Comment: @PlasmaHH yeah my thoughts too, annoyingly!. so much for standardised USB

Comment: This is well possible - there was a variety of 8-pin "mini" USB connectors, but they were vendor-specific. Digital cameras had them quite often.

Comment: Maybe micro HDMI? (it's a camera after all) with some of the pins repurposed for charging? (which ones is an interesting question)

Comment: @peufeu HDMI is ten pin unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried a Google search with "AOBO spy camera charging cable"? I did that and got lots of hits.

Comment: @MichaelKaras the first thing i did was google it. unless google prioritizes our hits in different ways, then all i got were links to the camera itself. I had one cable link which was on amazon but unavailable, the picture infact showed a USB type mini B rather than whatever this is

Comment: Mini USB or micro HDMI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a mini-B 8-pin USB port. The cable looks like this:

[image]

It was/is a pretty popular cable for Nikon CoolPix cameras. Surprisingly Amazon sells it.

Comment: You can't say "mini-B 8-pin USB port". There is no such thing in USB. There are proprietary connectors used as USB and maybe something else, but these are not any established standard ports. Panasonic also used to use some smaller form-actor connectors, but it doesn't make them mini- or micro- or else, they are "proprietary", and needs proprietary cables to operate.

Comment: @AliChen, I **can** say that, because that is the term used if you actually want to find it. I didn't say it is a standard of any sort. But it is used for a connection to the PC that follows the USB protocol, it has 8 pins and the manufacturers identify it as mini-B. OP is asking for help identifying his port and **this** is what it is if he wants to buy a cable.

Comment: @Catsunami certianly looks the right size, and searching  "mini-b 8-pin USB port" brings it up for me and provides links to amazon in google. I'll purchase and try it out, if it works ill give you the answer confirm!

Comment: When you say "mini-B", you imply that it is the standard, because "mini-B" is an established USB standard term. This is misuse of terminology. There are a lot of confused sellers who say "8-pin" yet selling standard mini-micro cables. There is no excuse to spread wrong information here.

Comment: Cable arrived this morning and it worked. I agree with Ali's comments in that it shouldn't be mini-b, but that is the search term that yielded the result i needed.

Comment: @AliChen, so I suppose it's better to just not answer OP's question? That does not create a good Q&A environment if all answers are simply "it's proprietary".

Comment: @Catsunami, no, it is better to call it in a technically correct way: "a proprietary connector sometimes illegally called "mini-B 8-pin USB". Then I would have no objection.

Comment: @AliChen, well if it's "illegal" then you can start writing letters to the manufacturers and threaten to sue. Me calling it a mini-B 8-pin USB will not change anything.

Comment: @Catsunami, "Me calling it a mini-B 8-pin USB will not change anything", it's not true, it doesn't improve your engineering reputation.

Comment: @AliChen, calling a USB cable what it is in order to help someone does not negatively affect my engineering reputation. I would be sad to work in a place where I was judged for pedantic naming conventions that prevent useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a proprietary connector for Nikon Coolpix cameras. There is no USB standard small-formfactor connector with 8-pins, and designatin the connector as "Mini-B" is misuse of USB terminology. This one is proprietary, and requires a proprietary cable assembly to operate.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is USB Mini A. It's rare, but you do occasionally find one.

It is known from USB OTG (on the go) for example used on the Texas Instruments TI-84 calculator.

[image: usb mini overview]

Comment: They're 5 pin though, so don't think it's that.

Comment: @Pop24 The shape of metal housing clearly is closer to mini-A than to mini-B. So the connector should be marketed as "mini-A 8-pin USB connector", not "mini-B".

Comment: @AliChen i dont name the products, searching for mini b 8 pin worked. cable arrived this morning and its functioning correctly. As you said its proprietary so its unlikely anyone will find this question and its answers of any use, but mini b 8 pin was the term that answered my question with success